# работа с map c++

Tags: c++, коллекции, map

я изучаю с++ и в данный момент мне необходимо разобраться с структурой данных map. Как я понял, map автоматически сортирует её содержимое, но мне нужно, чтобы всё содержимое map осталось в таком порядке, в котором я его в неё поместил. Вот кусочек моего кода:

```
std::map<std::string, int> months = {{"Jan",31}, {"Feb",28}, {"Mar",31},
                                        {"Apr",30}, {"Mai",31}, {"Jun",30},
                                        {"Jul",31}, {"Aug",31}, {"Sep",30}, 
                                        {"Oct",31}, {"Nov",30}, {"Dec",31},
    };
```

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: Если сортировка не нужна, то что заставляет использовать именно map? Добавьте отдельный `std::vector<std::string>` с именами месяцев.

Comment: map я использую потому, что мне нужно хранить месяцы и количество дней в них.  
Не очень понимаю, как с помощью вектора я смогу хранить значения в таком же формате... Не могли бы вы на примере показать?

Comment: Есть для этого `std::unordered_map`. Этот контейнер не сортирует содержимое. В данном случае он будет несколько эффективнее вектора с линейной скоростью поиска против константной.

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov, но и порядок в нём не определён, а по теме, раз всего два поля то есть std::pair

Comment: @Arenoros, да, спутал немного. Почему-то подумал, что оно хранит в порядке складывания элементы.

Comment: std::vector< std::pair< std::string, int> > > months;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример для вектора и структуры

```
int main()
{
    struct Month
    {
        std::string name;
        int days;
    };

    std::vector<Month> months{ 
        { "Jan", 31 }, { "Feb", 28 }, { "Mar", 31 }, { "Apr", 30 }, { "May", 31 }, { "Jun", 30 },
        { "Jul", 31 }, { "Aug", 31 }, { "Sep", 30 }, { "Oct", 31 }, { "Nov", 30 }, { "Dec", 31 } };

    for (const auto& it : months)
    {
        std::cout << it.name << "\t" << it.days << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```